# why did amount of data from bigquery decrease noticeably without any change in ga/firebase options?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, data-pipeline

I use Bigquery to get raw data from ga and firebase.
I could get about 100000 ~ 200000 rows of log data from Bigquery.

But since last week, I got about 1000 rows from Bigquery.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Laqsl.png)

I didn't change any options for ga, firebase, bigquery.
And I find that there's no change in data shown in ga.

AS I think, there's problem in connection ga to bigquery and firebase to bigquery.

How can I find the problems and reasons in connection?
I need a lot of opinions with this problems

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you need to check for data in source and ideally it should be available over target through integration. Comparing source and target you will get a clear picture whether there is a leak in integration or not.
If you see any data leak over data integration then you need to identify leaks reason through logs, or network/infra team. You need to find trace why this data leak was done. Then take corrective measure to fix it.

Overall conclusion is to identify data leak and get it fix.